# Convertir este código javascript en reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, javascript-objeto

Hola estoy aprendiendo a usar Reactjs por lo que necesito orientación para pasar este código que tengo en javascript a mi app en reactjs

Este es el codigo que tengo en javascript:

```
const data_api = await fetch(url, requestOptions)
  const res = await data_api.json();
  const res_data = res.data
 
  const arr = Object.entries(res_data);
  
  const arr1 = Object.keys(arr[1][1])
 
  let boton = ``;
  arr1.forEach((el) => {
    boton += `
     <div class='containerGame'>
           <button>${el}</button>
       </div> `

  });
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = boton;
```

Aqui es donde necesito hacer los mismo que hice en javascript.

Archivo Reactjs:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getData } from '../functions/functions';

const CreateReport = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData(setData)
  }, [])

  return (
      <div>
      </div>
  )
}

export default CreateReport;
```

Este es mi archivo donde consumo la api que estoy exportando a mi archivo en Reactjs

```
export const getData = (state) => {

  const config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/cubo/api/ventas?empresa=63&periodo=202202',
    headers: {
      'token': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }
  };

  axios(config)
    .then(response => state(response.data.data))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

Agradecida si me pueden orientar o brindar recursos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece estar todo bien, podrias probar agregando un `useEffect` asi, para asegurarte que estas recibiendo la data (despues podrias borrarlo, es solo para verificar):

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(data)
}, [data])
```

Si data tiene lo que vos esperas, solo deberias hacer en tu componente `createReport`:

```
return (
      <div id="container">
          {data.lenght > 0 && data.map((el,index) => {
               return(
                      <div className='containerGame' key='index'>
                        <button>{el}</button>
                      </div>
                      )
               })
           }
      </div>
  )
```